# How can I build a single machine learning model, than can classify an image and then draw bounding boxes around all the labels inside that image?

Tags: object-detection, multiclass-classification, image-classification

Suppose I have a dataset with images of cats, dogs, giraffes, lions, crocodiles and other animals(here they are the labels). Consider I have in total `n` labels. A single image may contain one or more animals of a single type. That is, an image of the lion may contain multiple lions in it, but no other labels(animals).

I have to make an ML model, that first classifies an image into a particular label, and then uses object detection, to draw bounding boxes around all the particular animal(or label) in that image.

How can I achieve this by using minimal ML model files(like .h5 or .pth files)?

An obvious brute force approach would be to build a classifier model, that can classify an image into its particular label and then build object detection models for the `n` labels(here animals) and use the appropriate model to get bounding boxes. But this would result in a total of `n+1` ML models, and I don't want this to happen. I would like to have minimal ML models and get the task done.

Is it possible to do this with just two ML models or just one?
How can I effectively crack this problem?

Edit: My primary aim is to use the information, I get from the classifier model, in object detection to improve its accuracy.

Suppose my classifier identified the image as a lion, Then I want the model, that's trained to identify the bounding box of a lion to be employed to find the bounding boxes in the image, than a multi-class object detection model which is trained on all labels(here animals).

I wish to do this because, in my use case, the labels are similar and a multi-class image detection model may have reduced accuracy.

Comment: So, you want something like [multi-class object detection](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2020/10/12/multi-class-object-detection-and-bounding-box-regression-with-keras-tensorflow-and-deep-learning/)?

Comment: @dratenik I have edited the question, to give more clarity.

Comment: The other obvious brute-force approach would be to vary the image, a.k.a "what's the smallest subimage that still gets classified as a lion". With something like a binary search for the bounds.